# unable to build my project due to error in refreshing omnetpp makefiles

Tags: omnet++

I am working on omnetpp project and when I try to build the project the following error message appears can any one help me please
[image]

Comment: If you have build issues, it's an absolute MUST to provide software versions in your description. There is no way someone would answer your question that some version of omnet++ does'n now build some version of INET.

Comment: I had download a project from github https://github.com/rtqayyum/mFogSim. the project author state that this project need omnet++ 4.6 and Inet 3.6.4, I worked on it on windows 10 ant the project worked properly, but when I transfer the work to ubuntu a build error appears

Comment: That must be a typo. Probably meant omnet 5.6. inet 3.3 was the last version that supported omnet 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build a relatively new version of INET with a very old version of OMNeT++. OMNET 4.6 is old, INET will not build with that.